# Is it possible to use cache for Git pre-commit hook?

Tags: git, caching, git-commit, pre-commit-hook, jscs

I use a pre-commit hook to check code-style and other rules for my project.

```
gulp.task('git-preCommit', ['jscs', 'jshint', 'tslint', 'stylint']);
```

Often this process is long-running. I wonder, is it possible to set some cache for changed files in Git, or in jscs, jshint etc.

For example there are 150 diff files, `preCommit` checked 149 successfully and threw an error on 1 (`path/example.ts`). I fix the last one, and when I commit next time - `git cache` (or some tools) will know that I fixed only 1 file and check only this one, not all 150.

Comment: Surely that's a matter of configuring the tools you're using,  nothing to with the commit hook *per se*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git does not have any cache mechanism or support for content.

So the simple answer is **NO**, it cant be done within git.
You can still use any 3rd party tool which might be suitable for you.